# Pointer inside a class

Tags: c++, class, pointers, queue

I have been working on class which works with queue operations of insert delete and display!! heres the code if you would like to try !! This code doesnt work with self referencial pointerss !!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

class queue
{
public:
static int *front;
static int *rear;
int info[5];

public:
void reset()
{
    front=&info[0];
    rear=&info[0];
}
void insert_rear(int item)
{
    if(rear>&info[4])
    {
        cout<<"Queue Overflow !!!"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    ++(*rear)=item;
    return;
}

void delete_front()
{
    if(front<&info[0])
    {
        cout<<"Queue Underflow !!!"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"The deleted item is : "<<(*front)--<<endl;
    if(front<rear)
    {
        reset();
    }
    return;

}

void display()
{
    int *i;
    for(i=front;i<=rear;i++)
    {
        cout<<*i<<endl;
    }
    return;
}
    };

    void main()
    {
queue database;
int choice,item;
database.reset();

for(;;)
{
    cout<<"1:Insert 2:Delete 3:Display 4:Exit"<<endl;
    switch(choice)
    {
    case 1: cout<<"Enter the item you want to insert : "<<endl;
        cin>>item;
        database.insert_rear(item);
        break;
    case 2: database.delete_front();
        break;
    case 3: database.display();
        break;
    default:cout<<"Exiting !!"<<endl;
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

}

This isnt working its a basic operation of a queue using a class !! Plz help me out here !!

Answer (score 1):

This is a mistake

```
static int *front;
static int *rear;
int info[5];
```

should be

```
int *front;
int *rear;
int info[5];
```

This is too confusing (and wrong too I think)

```
++(*rear)=item;
```

do it the simple way

```
*rear = item;
++rear;
```

The logic in

```
void delete_front()
{
    if(front<&info[0])
    {
        cout<<"Queue Underflow !!!"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout<<"The deleted item is : "<<(*front)--<<endl;
    if(front<rear)
    {
        reset();
    }
    return;

}
```

is wrong should be something like

```
void delete_front()
{
    if(front == rear)
    {
        cout<<"Queue Underflow !!!"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    cout << "The deleted item is : "<< *front <<endl;
    ++front;
    if(front == rear)
    {
        reset();
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to lose the pointer values once the object calls a member function .. as you see i have to RETAIN values of front and rear once the object is called up again

Comment: if the pointer rear points to info[3] .. next time i call it ,,it has to point to info[3] only !!

Comment: @TathagatNawadia I don't think you understand static. It's wrong to use in this case. But if you don't want to take my advice you don't have to

Comment: Like I said static is wrong, you do not need it. The pointers in your class will get RETAINED anyway

Comment: Thanks mate ... sry !! i was making a big blunder .!! It will indeed retain value !! (y)

Answer (score 1):

In the places where you write `++(*rear)` and `(*front)--`, try using 
`*(++rear)` and `*(front--)`, respectively - in that way, you will increment/decrement the pointer (as you intend), and not the value it points to

Comment: Thanks i did juss that .. instead i did the initialization first and then the increment ... but still it doesnt answer this ... why not use static

Comment: I don't think the use of static should make a difference here - it only affects the visibility of the variable across compilation units, if it is declared outside a function

Comment: Sorry, that comment above is wrong, I didn't get that you are using static variables in a class. If you want this to work, you have to also define (not only declare) front and rear somewhere, like so: int* queue::front(NULL); But I have to agree with john - it does not seem to make much sense